# Unable to load graphic environment, an X server problem

Tags: xorg, 64-bit

I have just installed ubuntu-desktop from command line, since an error during installation had me stuck on it. Now I'm still stuck there: if I try to boot normally, there will be just a blank screen, not even the splash screen.

If I use `startx` it terminates with error, saying "unable to connect to x server: no such file or directory".

If I use `Xorg -configure`, it throws "no devices to configure, configuration failed". Do you think is a problem with the drivers or something? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Shift key while your computer is booting up, and don't let go until it actually shows the grub menu

choose recovery mode and from there update your system using `sudo apt-get update` and check for the problem by reviewing `dmesg`